# Left/right and bottom/top axes manipulation in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to manipulate with the right Y-axis using "axis.line.y.right" but the axis doesn't change. I used the following theme but only the left Y-axis and bottom X-axis changed their color and size according to the desired parameters. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thank you so much.

```
 C57.sum
 Genotype Group Strain   my_mean CI.plus CI.minus  my_n
 WT       C57BL C57BL/6J   0.403   0.482    0.319    12





my.theme = list(theme(axis.line.y.left = element_line(size = 3, color = "red"),
                      axis.line.y.right = element_line(size = 3, color = "red"),
                      axis.line.x.top =  element_line(size = 3, color = "red"),
                      axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(size = 3, color = "red")),
                ylim(0,5))


Plot <- ggplot() +
  
  geom_bar(data = C57.sum, 
           aes(y = my_mean, x = Strain, fill=Group),
           color="black", stat="identity", width = 0.6, show.legend = FALSE,
           position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
  
  geom_linerange(data = C57.sum, 
                 aes(x = Strain, ymin = CI.minus, ymax = CI.plus),
                 color = "black", size = 0.42, 
                 position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = 0.6)) +
  

  geom_text(data = C57.sum, 
            aes(y = 0, x = Strain, group = Group, label=paste0("n = ",my_n), vjust=1.4),
            size = 2.8, fontface = "italic", position = position_dodge(0.6)) +
  
  coord_fixed(ratio=4/5) +
  my_theme.2

  Plot
```

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible without seeing the rest of your code that produced your plot, though I suppose `ylim(0, 5)` might have something to do with it (it could have overridden an earlier row for `scale_y_**` that included specifications for the right y-axis).

Comment: thank you for comment...I've added rest of the code

Comment: We don't have your data. Can this problem be represented using a common dataset available in R (e.g. mtcars)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to add the axes at the right and top first before theme elements affecting these axes have any effect. If there is nothing generating the top or right axes, they won't be drawn. Here are two examples using the `guides()` function and the `sec.axis` arguments.

```r
library(ggplot2)

my.theme = list(theme(axis.line.y.left = element_line(size = 3, color = "red"),
                      axis.line.y.right = element_line(size = 3, color = "red"),
                      axis.line.x.top =  element_line(size = 3, color = "red"),
                      axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(size = 3, color = "red")))


ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(x.sec = "axis", y.sec = "axis") +
  my.theme
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x)) +
  my.theme
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Alternatively you can also set e.g. `scale_x_continuous(position = "top")`, but then the bottom axes won't be drawn.